# IQueryable Extension - queryExpression filter is always null

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable Extension method that needs to call another class that inherits from ExpressionVisitor.

I've been trawling the internet for some code examples and have found the following:

```
public static string ToODataString<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    var internalQueryFields = query.GetType().GetFields(
               BindingFlags.Instance |
               BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    var internalQueryField = internalQueryFields.Where(f => f.Name.Equals("queryExpression")).FirstOrDefault();
    var internalQuery = internalQueryField.GetValue(query);

    var type = internalQuery.GetType();

    var objectQueryFields = internalQuery.GetType().GetFields(
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

    var objectQueryField = objectQueryFields.Where(f => f.Name.Equals("_arguments")).FirstOrDefault();

    var item = objectQueryField.GetValue(internalQuery) as IReadOnlyCollection<Expression>;

    var quote = item.Where(t => t.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote).FirstOrDefault() as UnaryExpression;

    var translator = new ODataTranslator();
    return translator.Translate(quote.Operand as LambdaExpression);
}
```

I am using the extension like this.....

```
var orders = new List<SalesOrder>();
var filterString = orders.Where(x => x.CustomerName == "Simple Filter").AsQueryable().ToODataString();
```

However the variable internalQueryField  is always null as the name queryExpression is never found, there is property with the name "expression" but that then causes the code to fail because the "item" variable is null.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Should `ToAzureSearchFilter` actually be `ToODataString`?

Comment: Can we see exactly how `queryExpression` is declared? Is it a field or a property? Is it capitalized differently? Is it a member of an interface that was implemented explicitly? Is it a member of `T` rather than a member of `IQueryable<T>`? Is it public? Is it static?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to debug your method `string ToODataString<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)`
and see line by line what is what. The variable: `internalQueryFields` is always null because doesn't contains any object in with the name: '*queryExpression*'.

Since I don't have enough detail about your question I assume that you class is something like this:

```
public class SalesOrder
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

And you mean this:

```
var orders = new List<SalesOrder>() { new SalesOrder() {  CustomerName = "Simple Filter" } };

var filterString = orders.Where(x => x.CustomerName == "Simple Filter").AsQueryable().ToODataString();
```

Debugging I found that there is no *queryExpression*, but: `_expression` and `_enumerable`.

[image]

[image]